# Strip a character from a string and make a list (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string like

```
'13:18:52.196339'
```

I want to strip ':', and then make store each number into a list, like:

```
[13,18,52,196339]
```

I am new to Python and can't figure out a way to do this. Please help.
Thank you :)

Comment: Did you intend to also split on the `'.'`?

Comment: @Turksarama Yes, and make a list of numbers like [13,18,52,196339]

Comment: If you have so many of them, it's better if you use a regular expression. Check out python library [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` function but first you need to replace your `.` with `:`

```
a = '13:18:52.196339'
x = a.replace('.',':')
z = x.split(':')
```

and you will get `['13', '18', '52', '196339']`. To get an array of integers,

```
z = list(map(int, z))
```

now you will get `[13, 18, 52, 196339]`

Answer (score 1):

```
S= '13:18:52.196339'
A = [int(i) for i in S.replace('.', ':').split(':')]
```